# Pick each file in a folder as a single log entry in elastic search with Logstash and Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat, elk

I have a requirement where my elk has to pick each file in a folder as a single log.
I have parent_folder/ inside which a folder will be created for a run run_folder/ inside which a few types of log files are created. I need to push each file as a single log into elastic search.

```
Folder Structure
parent_folder/run1/file1.log
parent_folder/run1/file2.err
parent_folder/run1/file3.diff
              ...
parent_folder/run2/file1.log
parent_folder/run2/file2.err
parent_folder/run2/file3.diff
```

Elastic search should have

```
doc1{
message: the content of parent_folder/run1/file1.log
}
doc2{
message: the content of parent_folder/run1/file2.err
}
doc3{
message: the content of parent_folder/run2/file2.err
}
... so on
```

These files like parent_folder/run2/file2.err are written once and never changed or touched again, no need to monitor for changes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With filebeat, you can make use of multiline patterns. Find a pattern that never match on your log file and configure something like below in filebeat configuration.

```
 multiline.pattern: 'never_matching_pattern'
 multiline.match: after
```

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-send-the-entire-logfile-as-a-single-message/118265

Comment: Yes, but the only problem is these files will not be deleted or modified ever, so filebeat will keep monitoring these files which grow in huge numbers. I want filebeat to ignore a file once it is processed.

Comment: For that purpose you have to use configuration `clean_inactive` together with `ignore_older` on Filebeat configuration. For example `ignore_older: 24h`, `clean_inactive: 25h`. `ignore_older` will make sure no harvest happens for files modification time older than 24 hours. And `clean_active` will make sure files inactive for 25 hours will be removed from registry file.

Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-clean-inactive

Comment: looks doable, I will try it. Thanks